# Selecting Collada groups and children by name

Tags: three.js

I am loading a Cinema4D generated Collada file into Three.js. I've learned from other postings that you can select and modify the individual children with `dae.children[i];` but is there a way to select them by their name?

Also, you can group children in Cinema4D. Is there a way to select those groups by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object3D`'s `getChildByName` method is probably what you're after.
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/49/#Object3D

Comment: When I attempt to use `dae.getChildByName( 'Cube', true )`, which there is a slight chance I'm using it wrong, I get that it is undefined. When I look in the collada file, there is a child named 'Cube'. I uploaded the sample to show you, but now it seems it only works on my local via Firefox. http://216.36.114.20/3d/index.html Should I post this as a separate Question?

Comment: Ahh, yes! It looks like our server needed the .dae MIME type added. The file is now loading properly. I am using the syntax `dae.getChildByName( 'Cube', true ).material.visible=false;`. Is that wrong?

Comment: When I attempt to `alert(dae.getChildByName('Cube', true))` it returns undefined. I checked my collada file and it looks to have `<node id="ID50" name="Cube">` which I'm guessing is where the name is specified. Is there something I could do to check which children are available in the scene? Or maybe another way I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Try doing console.log(dae) in Chrome and open the console :)

Comment: That opens up a whole new world of.. detail! Thanks so much and awesome library! It seems the `.getChildByName` id pulling the ID from the node instead of the name given in Cincema4D. Good to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dae.getChildByName( 'ID50', true )
```

is WORKING.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping I could get the child by using the object name within Cinema4D. The **ID50** ID seems to be automated.